# Strange response when finding documents in MongoDB using Mongoose in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Thanks in advance for your help on this, it's much appreciated!

I'm using Node.js, MongoDB and Mongoose in a new project and I'm simply trying to `find()` the documents in a database. For brevity I'll just include the Mongoose code below (I'm not doing much more than this anyway right now):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://<username>:<password>@<sub-domain>.mongolab.com:<port>/<db>');

var schema = { email_address: String, invite: String }
  , Users = mongoose.model('Users', new mongoose.Schema(schema));

console.log(Users.findOne({ 'email_address': 'jonathon@foo.bar' }, function(err, doc) { return doc; }));
```

I'm quite sure that should just echo the returned `doc` to the Node.js console (Terminal) but instead I'm getting this:

```
{ options: { populate: {} },
  safe: undefined,
  _conditions: { email_address: 'jonathon@foo.bar' },
  _updateArg: {},
  _fields: undefined,
  op: 'findOne',
  model: 
   { [Function: model]
     modelName: 'Users',
     model: [Function: model],
     options: undefined,
     db: 
      { base: [Object],
        collections: [Object],
        models: {},
        replica: false,
        hosts: null,
        host: '<sub-domain>.mongolab.com',
        port: <port>,
        user: '<username>',
        pass: '<password>',
        name: '<db>',
        options: [Object],
        _readyState: 2,
        _closeCalled: false,
        _hasOpened: false,
        db: [Object] },
     schema: 
      { paths: [Object],
        subpaths: {},
        virtuals: [Object],
        nested: {},
        inherits: {},
        callQueue: [],
        _indexes: [],
        methods: {},
        statics: {},
        tree: [Object],
        _requiredpaths: undefined,
        options: [Object] },
     collection: 
      { collection: null,
        name: 'users',
        conn: [Object],
        buffer: true,
        queue: [Object],
        opts: {} },
     base: 
      { connections: [Object],
        plugins: [],
        models: [Object],
        modelSchemas: [Object],
        options: {},
        Collection: [Function: NativeCollection],
        Connection: [Function: NativeConnection],
        version: '3.5.4',
        Mongoose: [Function: Mongoose],
        Schema: [Object],
        SchemaType: [Object],
        SchemaTypes: [Object],
        VirtualType: [Function: VirtualType],
        Types: [Object],
        Query: [Object],
        Promise: [Function: Promise],
        Model: [Object],
        Document: [Object],
        Error: [Object],
        mongo: [Object] } } }
```

Obviously I've just obfuscated my real credential with the `<username>` bits, they are all correct in my code.

The database does have a document in it that would match the condition though even removing the condition from the `findOne` method yields no results!

I'm fairly new to Node.js so I you could explain your answers so I know for next time it'd be a great help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I totally forget, Node.js is asynchronous so the line `console.log(Users.findOne({ 'email_address': 'jonathon@foo.bar' }, function(err, doc) { return doc; }));` is indeed echoing to the console though no documents have been returned by the DB yet!

Instead the `console.log` method should be inside the `find`'s callback, a la:

```
Users.find({}, function(err, doc) { console.log(doc); });
```

Answer (score 4):

Change your code to:

```
Users.findOne({ 'email_address': 'jonathon@foo.bar' }, function(err, doc) {
 console.log(doc); 
});
```

I can't see from your code, but I think you are writing the value of the mongoose function to the console...